# Office 365 Outlook, not receving mails

Tags: office365, mailgun

I am using Mail-gun in Ruby on Rails application for sending email,
its sending mail to google and outlook accounts, but when sent to office 365, I am not receiving any email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with email bouncing when sent to Outlook via the Mailgun API. For the record I use their free plan, which means I share an IP with multiple other users. See below the error message I get.

My fix (which is only temporary) was to contact their support and ask for an IP switch. They changed it to an IP with a better reputation, the email got delivered but now I'm back to this error. I read on several threads that getting their paid plan with a dedicated IP might solve this issue.

`Server response: 451 4.7.650 The mail server [198.61.254.31] has been temporarily rate limited due to IP reputation. For e-mail delivery information, see https://postmaster.live.com (S843) [CO1NAM05FT016.eop-nam05.prod.protection.outlook.com]`

Answer (score 0):

In the event that you were expecting an email and it never showed up or are missing new messages in Microsoft Outlook, investigating can assist you with pinpointing and resolve the issue. We set up data about normal reasons why Outlook isn’t accepting messages to assist you with getting back going.
http://how-tofix.com/resolve-outlook-when-not-receiving-emails/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.